# C# XML - add list of objects to root element

Tags: c#, xml

I have a little problem with the XML API of C#. I have the following code to save a list of objects into a xml file:

```
public void Export(List<Booking> bookings)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "zeitbuchungen.xml");

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    XPathNavigator xmlNavigator = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xmlNavigator.AppendChild())
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Booking>), new XmlRootAttribute("Bookings"));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, bookings);
    }
    xmlDocument.Save(path);
}
```

The problem is, if I call this method again, the file - of course - gets replaced, but I want to add the new list to the file.

This is how the file should look like, if i call the method twice:

```
<Bookings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Booking>
    <SerialNumberTerminal>1234567890</SerialNumberTerminal>
    <TransponderID>FBbNAx75KHjN</TransponderID>
    <BookingDateTime>2016-03-19T20:21:01</BookingDateTime>
    <BookingCommand>G</BookingCommand>
  </Booking>
  <Booking>
    <SerialNumberTerminal>1234567890</SerialNumberTerminal>
    <TransponderID>wJAo3EGsuSRI</TransponderID>
    <BookingDateTime>2016-03-19T20:21:01</BookingDateTime>
    <BookingCommand>G</BookingCommand>
  </Booking>
</Bookings>
```

I already figured out, that I can load the existing file with `xmlDocument.Load(path)`, but I don't know how to add the new list to the root element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the file and then add elements to the rood what you already did. I tried to make this kind of code. I hope this will help you to the right way. :)

```
public void Export(List<Booking> bookings)
{
    string path =Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "zeitbuchungen.xml");
    //This block is what you need to add
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    //////////////////
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xmlNavigator.AppendChild())
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =( doc, new XmlRootAttribute("Bookings"));

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, bookings);
        fs.Close();
    }
    }
    xmlDocument.Save(path);
}
```